# how to display 2 UL's and LI's responsive nav menus on the same html page

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am trying to create two responsive navigation menus in css.
However I have tried div class, ul class etc and they menu's don't load correctly.
I would very much appreciate any help or feedback.

Some code samples:
html:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <nav class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
        <ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and the second menu

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css:

```
/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #455868;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4;
}
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

/*Start of 2nd menu info*/
.menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    position: absolute;
 }

.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
 }

.menu li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:100px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.menu li:hover a {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.menu li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #990000;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

.menu li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}


.menu ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #990000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu2{
    display: block;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu3{
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
nav { 
    height: auto;
}
nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
}
nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
}

/*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
.menu ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
}
/*Create vertical spacing*/
.menuli {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
/*Make all menu links full width*/
.menu ul li, li a {
    width: 100%;
}
/*Display 'show menu' link*/
.show-menu {
    display:block;
}
    /*Display 'show menu2' link*/
.show-menu2 {
    display:block;
}
    /*Display 'show menu2' link*/
.show-menu3 {
    display:block;
}

}
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
}
nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
nav a#pull:after {
    content:"";
    background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
}
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
.menu ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
}
/*Create vertical spacing*/
.menuli {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
/*Make all menu links full width*/
.menu ul li, li a {
    width: 100%;
}
/*Display 'show menu' link*/
.show-menu {
    display:block;
}
    /*Display 'show menu2' link*/
.show-menu2 {
    display:block;
}
    /*Display 'show menu2' link*/
.show-menu3 {
    display:block;
}
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
}
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
.menu ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
}
/*Create vertical spacing*/
.menuli {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
/*Make all menu links full width*/
.menu ul li, li a {
    width: 100%;
}
/*Display 'show menu' link*/
.show-menu {
    display:block;
}
    /*Display 'show menu2' link*/
.show-menu2 {
    display:block;
}
    /*Display 'show menu2' link*/
.show-menu3 {
    display:block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp54w38b/

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-position" role="navigation">  

<div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation"> 
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Button</button>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
    <div class="navbar-text">Text</div>
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-position {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar{
    margin: 0;
}
```